# MySQL - How to select records without duplicate records

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with 3 columns like this:

```
+----+---------+--------+-------+
| Id | Country | Number | State |
+----+---------+--------+-------+
| 1  | Canada  | 12     | 0     |
+----+---------+--------+-------+
| 2  | Canada  | 14     | 0     |
+----+---------+--------+-------+
| 3  | USA     | 10     | 2     |
+----+---------+--------+-------+
| 4  | Germany | 8      | 1     |
+----+---------+--------+-------+
```

These are many records in this table.
I need to have country names without any duplikate. I used DISTINCT in the from below but I could not achieve an appropriate result.

**SELECT DISTINCT country, number, state FROM tbl_country;**

My desired result is something like this (only unique country names):

```
+---------+--------+-------+
| USA     | 10     | 2     |
+---------+--------+-------+
| Germany | 8      | 1     |
+---------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Does your table have a primary key

Comment: Yes, I have primary key (id column).

Comment: Why does SELECT DISTINCT not work, it only returns all records - including duplicate ones. I know that I need to display only unique records, but DISTINCT should not display duplicate records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using a subquery, you can achieve your desired output.
First group by country and count how many appearances there are and then filter
to get the countries that are in the subquery. Later get the final output

```
SELECT country, number, state
FROM tbl_country
WHERE country IN (
    SELECT country 
    FROM tbl_country 
    GROUP BY country 
    HAVING COUNT(country) = 1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using mysql 8, you can use the window function `COUNT()` to compute the count for each country, and then filter the results to include only those with a count of 1.

```
SELECT Country, Number, State
FROM (
  SELECT *, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Country ) as cnt
  FROM mytable
) AS s
WHERE cnt = 1;
```

Alternatively, you can do it by using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses, along with the aggregate function `MAX()` :

```
SELECT Country, MAX(Number) AS Number, MAX(State) AS State
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Country
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: v8 also supports [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions). You can move inner select from `FROM` to a CTE expression.